# Парсить ссылку при переходе на сайт

Tags: php, cookie

решил сделать партнерку, вот такого вида ссылка https://mysite.com/p644320/vip , где p644320 - это id того, кто привлекает, как мне при переходе на мой сайт обрабатывать этот id чтобы пользователь дальше перешел на страницу vip а не перенаправился на главную?

Comment: да, немного сменил структуру ссылки всегда будет в конце  https://mysite.com/vip/p644320, да первая буква p а дальше число - сам id

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью регулярных выражений

```
$str = 'mysite.com/vip/p644320';

preg_match('~(\pL{3})/(\pL\d+)~', $str, $arr);
list(, $vip, $id) = $arr;

var_dump($vip, $id);
```

И тогда можно парсить ссылки вида *mysite.com/vip/p644320/page* включительно.

Comment: то есть прописать в index.php такой код который будет  пихать в куки id 644320 и сразу удалять из конца урл p644320 ? А после этих процедур не будет перенаправлять на главную, а направит на vip?

Comment: @Aslero этот пример не модифицирует url. Здесь из url выделяется id и vip. Вам не помешает правильно составить первый пост с вопросом _(вы можете его отредактировать с учётом всех предпочтений)_

Comment: в вопросе и написано, получить id и перейти дальше по ссылке

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
$url = "https://mysite.com/p644320/vip";
$parse = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parse_arr = explode('/', $parse);
```

в `$parse_arr[1]` будет p644320
в `$parse_arr[2]` будет vip

Comment: а если будет например p644320 будет менять места "https://mysite.com/vip/p644320" или "https://mysite.com/vip/p644320/page"

Comment: Это уже другой формат ссылки я вам дал решение для той которую вы указали.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, хочется сказать немного о структуре роутинга для подобных задач.

### Критика вашего подхода

**Ваш подход не совсем удобен**, потому что вы собираетесь обрабатывать реферальную ссылку всего в одном месте, что не особо хорошо для реферера, который будет размещать ссылку на ваш ресурс.

Ведь задача реферера "**заманить**" человека на сайт любыми доступными способами, чтобы ему установилась кука и он зарегистрировался в дальнейшем на вашем ресурсе, а реферер с этого смог получать средства/бонусы и т.д. Он должен иметь возможность отправлять ссылки на любые ваши страницы со своей реферальной ссылкой.

Посмотрите на сотни других ресурсов, очень много ресурсов использует обычный query параметр ***?ref={id пользователя}*** и это в целом простое и правильное решение. Конечно, этот параметр раскрывает ID и может заставить человека попробовать ввести другое значение в это поле, в этом случае ресурсы принимают обычное хеширование или шифрование ID клиента, чтобы клиент не "**игрался**" этим параметром, но как правило в большем количестве случаев **нет никакого смысла этим заниматься**, а уж тем более с помощью перенаправления скрывать реферальную ссылку, потому что клиент который "жадный" и не хочет, чтобы с него получали прибыль, то он просто скопирует эту ссылку без реферальных элементов в URL.

Ведь намного проще, если это будет выглядеть вот так:

https://mysite.com/vip?ref=644320

### Реализация подхода

Если вы решите использовать мой вариант, то вам достаточно просто получить query параметр и записать его клиенту в куку. Вы можете это делать средствами фреймворка, а можете делать через чистый PHP кодом вроде:

```
<?php 
  $ref = $_GET['ref'];
?>
```

При использовании вашего подхода, я рекомендую вам использовать фреймворки (Symfony, Laverel, и т.д) или библиотеки для маршрутизации, которые позволяют с помощью аннотаций решить данную проблему в несколько строчек кода.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{clientId}/vip", requirements={"clientId" = "^p[0-9]+$"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
```

Представленная вами структура ссылки не совсем корректна (https://mysite.com/p644320/vip), потому что подобные страницы с динамическими идентификаторами в самом начале могут пересекаться со статичными маршрутами. Например, vip/{clientId} удобнее с точки зрения количества перебираемых маршрутов и логический отделяет раздел vip с параметром от остальных разделов.

Если без изменений писать предложенный вами вариант на чистом PHP, то это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
if (preg_match('/^\/(p[0-9]+)\/vip$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
   //Отправить заголовки Cookie или Location
}
```